# Asynchronous image loading error

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to loading images in tableViewCell asynchronously.
When I move the table up and down then images appear otherwise not.

AsyncImageView contains NSUrlConnection. It doesn't go inside the delegate "connectionDidFinishLoading". but when I move the table up or down then it goes inside this delegate function

Below is the code

```
        CGRect frame;
        frame.size.width=115; frame.size.height=100;
        frame.origin.x=0; frame.origin.y=0;
        AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc]
                                       initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        loadingTable=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:loadingTable];
        [loadingTable startAnimating];
        asyncImage.tag = 999;
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[videoCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] videoImageUrl] ];
        [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url activity:loadingTable];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load all images and add them some data structure like array and after that show it to the table. Don't overlap your UI with network calls.

Comment: but it displays images correctly when moving table up or down

Comment: then you'r delegate is not set properly

Comment: AsyncImageView contains NSUrlConnection. It doesn't go inside the delegate "connectionDidFinishLoading". but when I move the table up or down then it goes inside this delegate function.

Comment: yeah that is either your data finished loading when u scroll down, wait a while if data loads without scrolling

Comment: and if it not loads without scrolling, then you are initializing NSURLConnection at not proper place like in viwDidEndScrolling etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure as you know, all UI related business must be done on the main thread. However, downloading big amounts of data can and should be done in the background. And this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) with Grand Central Dispatch may be just what you need.

Download the images in a background thread and when its complete, let the main thread know of this and do the updating of the UI on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this yesterday.

The best way is to call the download in background and in the `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

This method will load the cell's image when the user would want to see it.

But warning ! To prevent downloading many time the same image, you should use a data structure (like dictionary) to check if the image has been downloaded.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    if([myPictures objectForKey:indexPath.row] == nil) {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadPhotoInBackground:) withObject:indexPath];
    }
    return cell
}
```

and in downloadPhotoInBackground:, don't forget to add your downloaded image to "myPictures" property.